# How to Format float value from 11111111 to 1,111,111.00?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, string-formatting

I've been all over the Internet, and since I have no much experience, I couldn't find a right solution.

As mentioned above, in my database I will have "big" values, where there are up to 9-10 digits, and I was requested to format them like, for example, instead of 23456789 -> 23,456,789.00, and show them like that in DataGrid.

This is how i populate DataGrid

```
probaDataContext proba = new probaDataContext();
        public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                dgData.ItemsSource = proba.ProbaTabelas.ToList();
    }
```

And this is my XAML code

I found a way how to Format them to 23,456,789  , but I still need those two digits behind, with the dot.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgData" Margin="89,0,118,165" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Numbernumber" Binding="{Binding cifra, StringFormat=\{0:N0\}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid
```

If the value is a whole number, they should be .00 , if a value has decimals like 23432.54, they should look like 23,432.54.

Comment: A single precision float only has 7 decimal digits of precision.  If you require 9-10 digits, then you should consider using a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:n}", 1234);  // Output: 1,234.00

String.Format("{0:n0}", 9876); // No digits after the decimal point. Output: 9,876
```

so I suppose that changing this

```
StringFormat=\{0:N0\}
```

to this

```
StringFormat=\{0:N\}
```

is ok for you.

***Note:*** Some cultures use `,` to mean decimal rather than `.` so be careful.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. How can I swap the meanings of , and . ?

Comment: 'CultureInfo' is the answer. 'new CultureInfo("en-US")' is not equal to 'new CultureInfo("en-IS")'
For example:

(19950000.0).ToString("N",new CultureInfo("en-US")) = 19,950,000.00
(19950000.0).ToString("N",new CultureInfo("is-IS")) = 19.950.000,00

Comment: Thank you again! Will try and use those things!